# What feature automatically adds "async" to a method signature in VS2022

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio 2022 appears to have a feature which automatically adds the `async` keyword to the current method signature if you type the `await` keyword.

For example, if I have a partially-written method

```cs
public class C
{
  public void M()
  {
    await//I'm still typing
  }
}
```

Then after pressing the spacebar after the "t" in "await", the method automatically becomes `async void`:

```cs
public class C
{
  public async void M()
  {
    await // I'm still typing, but I just completed the await keyword
  }
}
```

In the editor's undo list, the automatic addition of the `async` keyword is listed as an undo step called "Completion". I have IntelliCode activated.

I dislike this feature because I don't wish to add `async void` methods to my codebase without careful consideration. What Visual Studio feature is causing this behaviour, and how can I turn it off?

---

My visual studio version is

> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current 
> Version 17.1.1

Comment: I have the same question. I don't want VS adding "async" to create a lot of "async void" methods.